# Gstreamer filesink timestamp with a spotty data link

Tags: gstreamer

I am streaming h265 video over UDP with RTP.  The receiver pipeline is below, it decodes and displays the video, as well saving it with filesink.

```
udpsrc port=6014 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H265,payload=96 ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! tee name=t1 ! queue ! avdec_h265 ! xvimagesink sync=false async=false t1. ! queue ! mpegtsmux ! filesink location=%s.ts sync=true
```

The wireless data link which this video is streaming over is sometimes very intermittent.  When link quality is poor, the displayed video is pixelated or otherwise very bad quality.  When the link is gone altogether, the displayed video just stays on the last received frame.  When the link returns, the displayed video goes back to normal.  This is all fine and expected.

I have just a minor problem in the saved video.  When playing it back in eg. VLC, the timer doesn't advance during the periods with no link.  For example, if link was lost from t=10 s to t=30 s, then when the video playback gets to t=10 it will just look frozen (no advancing timestamp) until t=30, when it skips all the way to 30.  I think what's happening is there is no data at all during those times in between; what I'd like is to repeat the last frame instead.  Anyway for filesink to do that?  Or, is there something I can do in post-processing to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your requirements. You can't just "repeat" pictures in a compressed video bitstream. If you would use GStreamer itself for playback I would recommend to look at the `videorate` element. That one would repeat decoded pictures to create a consistent stream.

For a post production solution it may help to add a silent audio track. In that case the VLC player probably will advance its slider as desired as it will render (inaudible) audio data constantly.